# How to trim a string based on specific criteria in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: string, trim, progress-4gl, openedge

ABC+123:xy+123++23'EFG+123:xy+123++23'GHI+123:xy+123++23+mki+123'LMV++123:xy'

I have above string . Apostrophe(') acts as a terminator which denotes end of segments . 
Hence ABC+123:xy+123++23 is a segment , its start tag is three chars ABC which is unique.
Now I need to trim this string based on these start tags eg I need segments starting only with ABC and LMV .
resulting string should be ABC+123:xy+123++23'LMV++123:xy'

Answer (score 3):

Based on this question and your other questions you work with EDIFACT.

EDIFACT is delimited with the single quote ' (or apostrophe if you so will).

`ENTRY` and `NUM-ENTRIES` is your friend. I would suggest moving your data into a more usable format than a string - more precisely a temp-table. Then you can do whatever you want with the temp-table. First process the data "line by line" or rather "entry by entry" and then move on to do whatever you want with it.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cString AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iEntry  AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttEdifact NO-UNDO
    FIELD lineno   AS INTEGER
    FIELD linedata AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(60)".

/* The string in your example ends with a delimiter (') thus your temp-table will have one empty record in the end - it could be trimmed away */
cString = "ABC+123:xy+123++23'EFG+123:xy+123++23'GHI+123:xy+123++23+mki+123'LMV++123:xy'".


DO iEntry = 1 TO NUM-ENTRIES(cString, "'").
   CREATE ttEdiFact.
   ASSIGN 
       ttEdifact.lineno = iEntry
       ttEdifact.lineData = ENTRY(iEntry, cString, "'").
END.

/* Now it's up to you to do something */
FOR EACH ttEdifact WHERE ttEdifact.lineData BEGINS "ABC":
    DISP ttEdiFact.
END.
```

Comment: Yes I am working with edifact , somehow able to extract what each elements say , still fighting to get exact info I need , this question is to filter segment tags before parsing . Thanks .

Comment: BTW if you have earlier worked in edifact and have some working library is it possible to help me out with it , thanks

Comment: @mac100 We stopped working with EDIFACT some 10 years ago so I don't think we have anything useful left...